# How to loop throught table td and return a string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table (larger than this example)

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="chess_board">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="A8"><a class="rook black" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="B8"><a class="knight black" href="#">Cont1</a></td>
        <td id="C8"><a class="bishop black" href="#">Cont2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="A7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont3</a></td>
        <td id="B7"><a class="pawn black" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="C7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont4</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

In jquery, how do i loop through all td and return a string containg not empty td id and text? In this case a string

```
 "B8 Cont1 C8 Cont2 A7 Cont3 C7 Cont4"
```

I know the existence of the 'each' function but it's a callback and i can't build my string during the loop (do i?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick...

```
var text = "";
$("#chess_board").find("td").each(function() {
    if (this.id !== "" && this.innerText !== "") {
        text += this.id + " " + this.innerText + " ";
    }
});
console.log(text);
```

You nearly had it.  You just declare the string outside the `each()` function so it is available both during and afterwards.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Guess you can do this way:

```js
$(function () {
  var allString = "";
  $("#chess_board td[id]").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".black").html().trim().length > 0)
      allString += this.id + " " + $(this).find(".black").html().trim() + " ";
  });
  alert(allString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="chess_board">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="A8"><a class="rook black" href="#"></a></td>
      <td id="B8"><a class="knight black" href="#">Cont1</a></td>
      <td id="C8"><a class="bishop black" href="#">Cont2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="A7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont3</a></td>
      <td id="B7"><a class="pawn black" href="#"></a></td>
      <td id="C7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont4</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `each()`, you can use `map()` to create an array of the required values. From there you can `join()` the array to create the required string. Try this:

```js
var values = $('#chess_board td').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) != '';
}).map(function() {
  return $.trim(this.id + ' ' + $(this).text());
}).get();

console.log(values.join(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="chess_board">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="A8">
        <a class="rook black" href="#"></a>
      </td>
      <td id="B8"><a class="knight black" href="#">Cont1</a>
      </td>
      <td id="C8"><a class="bishop black" href="#">Cont2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="A7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont3</a>
      </td>
      <td id="B7">
        <a class="pawn black" href="#"></a>
      </td>
      <td id="C7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont4</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
var text = "";
$('td').each(function(index, elem) {
    if ($(elem).find('a').text() != '')
    {
        text += elem.id + ' ' + $(elem).find('a').text() + ' ';
    }
});
console.log(text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mgxa3k9g/

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays could be done in a more orderly way, an example:

```js
var result = [];

$("#chess_board td").each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  text.length && result.push($(this).attr("id") + " " + text);
});

console.log(result.join(" "))
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6voms50y/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery map()

```js
var tds = $("td");
var txt = tds.map( function () {
    var x = $.trim($(this).text());
    return x.length ? x : null
} ).get().join(" ");
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="chess_board">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="A8"><a class="rook black" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="B8"><a class="knight black" href="#">Cont1</a></td>
        <td id="C8"><a class="bishop black" href="#">Cont2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="A7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont3</a></td>
        <td id="B7"><a class="pawn black" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="C7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont4</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of use the `each` function u can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like this:

```js
    $(function () {
     var allString = [];
     allString = $("#chess_board td").map(function(){
      return $(this).find("a").html() != "" ? $(this).attr("id")+" "+$(this).find("a").html() : "";
       }).get();
       allString = allString.join(" ").trim();
       alert(allString);
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="chess_board">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="A8"><a class="rook black" href="#"></a></td>
          <td id="B8"><a class="knight black" href="#">Cont1</a></td>
          <td id="C8"><a class="bishop black" href="#">Cont2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="A7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont3</a></td>
          <td id="B7"><a class="pawn black" href="#"></a></td>
          <td id="C7"><a class="pawn black" href="#">Cont4</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```